# Run tasks asynchronously/concurrently/parallally in iOS swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, grand-central-dispatch, dispatch-queue

How can i executes all the above taks at one time for improving speed.

```
self.passingMsgIdsTofetchMsgss(messageIDs : msgIDBatches[0]) 

self.passingMsgIdsTofetchMsgss(messageIDs : msgIDBatches[1]) 

self.passingMsgIdsTofetchMsgss(messageIDs : msgIDBatches[2]) 

self.passingMsgIdsTofetchMsgss(messageIDs : msgIDBatches[3])
```

Comment: Post the contents of `getFullMail` method

Comment: Are you fetching data from the network? If so, it is unlikely that anything you do in your app will improve performance

Comment: I suggest printing the thread ID inside your `for` loop to verify whether you're getting concurrent execution.  What to adjust may depend on the answer.

Answer (score 1):

What you're after is the class function on DispatchQueue [concurrentPerform](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchqueue/2016088-concurrentperform)

For example:

```
DispatchQueue.concurrentPerform(iterations: msgIDBatches.count) { (index) in
    self.passingMsgIdsTofetchMsgss(messageIDs : msgIDBatches[index])    
}
```

You will obviously need to be careful around calling back on the main queue if you're updating UI and also ensure that `passingMsgIdsTofetchMsgss` is thread-safe. It is also worth checking using [time profiler](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/Instrument-TimeProfiler.html) that this is where the performance bottle-neck actually is.

Another option is `OperationQueue`, you can add all of your fetches to a queue and concurrently perform them.

Answer (score 0):

Swift 4.1. First create a concurrent Queue

```
private let concurrentPhotoQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "App_Name", attributes: .concurrent)
```

Now dispatch your work to Concurrent Queue

```
concurrentPhotoQueue.async(flags: .barrier) { [weak self] in
            // 1
            guard let weakSelf = self else {
                return
            }
            // 2 Perform your task here
            weakSelf.passingMsgIdsTofetchMsgss(messageIDs : msgIDBatches[0])
            weakSelf.passingMsgIdsTofetchMsgss(messageIDs : msgIDBatches[1])
            weakSelf.passingMsgIdsTofetchMsgss(messageIDs : msgIDBatches[2])
            weakSelf.passingMsgIdsTofetchMsgss(messageIDs : msgIDBatches[3])
            // 3
            DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
                // Update your UI here
            }
        }
```